# Entity Framework core 2.0 HasColumnType throw run time exception

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a custom enum type EmployementState (complex type in EF 6 term, I think)

in OnModelCreating, the following code throw an run time exception.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(e => e.EmployementState.Value).HasColumnType("int");
```

The exception show below:

```
  Message=The expression 'e => e.EmployementState.Value' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
```

cannot figure out how to get the syntax right or is there are something else I was missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error explain itself. The `.Property(e => e.EmployementState.Value)` is a virtual property i guess. You need to specify the configuration for `Entity<EmployementState>().Property(e => e.Value)` instead.

Comment: @cristian-szpisjak Thanks for your reply.  That does solve the run time exception.  But because EmployementState is a class, it will just create another table of EmployementState in the database.

Yet, I would like to just save the EmployementState  value inside the Employee Table as a column.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following model for your `EmployementState` object that will hold the different states for your employee:

```
public class EmployementState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then add a reference like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // All your user properties here

    public int EmployementStateId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployementState EmployementState { get; set; }
}
```

I recommend this because is the best approach when you are working with states describing your objects.

Of course being two separate models they are configurable so configurations like this one below are easy to implement.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(e => e.EmployementStateId)
    .HasColumnName("employement_state_ID");
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yet I would like to avoid having two properties for the same purpose.  I will look into this a little bit more.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think in this case is not a matter of avoidance because is the strong type way or using simple string. However this approach will eliminate most of the problems that may occur in the future.